# Binary search algorithm using `size_t` instead of using `int`

Tags: c++, c, binary-search, function-definition, size-t

This is the binary search algorithm from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). It uses `int` type indexing. The use of the `int` type here is necessary because the algorithm sometimes uses the negative index values while searching.

```
int binary_search(unsigned array[], int length, unsigned needle) {
  int l = 0, r = length - 1, m;
  while (l <= r) {
    m = (l + r) / 2;
    if (array[m] < needle)
      l = m + 1;
    else if (array[m] > needle)
      r = m - 1;
    else
      return m;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

How to modify this algorithm to use `size_t` (`unsigned int`) instead of `int`?

**What is an optimal solution for this?**

```
size_t binary_search(unsigned array[], size_t length, unsigned needle) {
  size_t l = 0, r = length - 1, m;

  ???

  return (size_t) -1;
}
```

Comment: *How to modify this algorithm to use size_t* -- `m = (l + r) / 2;` -- Possible overflow here: `(l + r)`

Comment: By revising the binary search algorithm to avoid `r = m - 1;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can we handle it? `m = l + (r - l) / 2`

Comment: @NoSkill Since you tagged C++, and if you have C++ 20, you can use [std::midpoint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint).

Comment: I don't know why people are concentrating on the possible overflow in `l+r`: on most implementations `array` cannot be large enough for it to happen in type size_t. It is the case if `sizeof(unsigned)>=2`, or if like gcc the compiler does not allow objects that occupy more than half the address space (and size_t matches that), or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Here you are.

As you specified the language tags C and C++ then the demonstration program below can be run in C and C++. That is there are no special features of C++ except using names `bool`, `false` and `true` that in C can be used if to include header `<stdbool.h>` Also in C you need to include header `<stdio.h>` instead of `<iostream>`

```
#include <iostream>

size_t binary_search( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    size_t left = 0, right = n, middle = 0;
    bool found = false;

    while ( !found && left != right )
    {
        middle = left + ( right - left ) / 2;

        if ( value < a[middle] )
        {
            right = middle;
        }
        else if ( a[middle] < value )
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    return found ? middle : -1;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( int value = 0; value <= a[N - 1] + 1; value++ )
    {
        size_t pos = binary_search( a, N, value );

        if ( pos != -1 )
        {
            printf( "%d is found at %zu.\n", value, pos );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%d is not found.\n", value );
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 is not found.
1 is found at 0.
2 is not found.
3 is found at 1.
4 is not found.
5 is found at 2.
6 is not found.
7 is found at 3.
8 is not found.
9 is found at 4.
10 is not found.
```

Pay attention to that in general in C++ you will need to write a template function while in C you will write the function similarly to the implementation of `bsearch`.

Without using the variable `found` the function can look as

```
size_t binary_search( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    size_t left = 0, right = n;

    while ( left != right )
    {
        size_t middle = left + ( right - left ) / 2;

        if ( value < a[middle] )
        {
            right = middle;
        }
        else if ( a[middle] < value )
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return middle;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Well... this solution sometimes will check the same index twice. Am I right?

Comment: @NoSkill In the nested if statements the expression a[middle] can be used twice if the first if statement evaluates to false. It is the same behavior as the behavior in your code provided in the question.

Comment: As `right` is out of range (the way I do it too) shouldn't the end condition be `right - left > 1`?

Comment: To summarize: this makes `right` an exclusive bound instead of an inclusive one.  This is usually how I do it, too.  And more generally, I find that representing intervals (such as the range of indices at which the target might appear) in half-open form tends to produce a lot of conveniences.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why can not right - left be equal to 1? In this case in any case if statements must be executed.

Comment: @WeatherVane, when `right == left + 1`, index `left` still has to be considered.  For example, when the whole array is length 1 (that is, `n == 1`), you still have to check element 0.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ah ok... I understand. So the nested range in this case can be a little bigger (+ one more element) as you remove `-1`.

Comment: @Vlad because at that point `left` is either matches or it does not: there are no other candidates. I check that after the search completes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I do that after the search completes.

Comment: @WeatherVane If left is equal to right then the range is empty. If right - left is equal to 1 then the range contains one element that must be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Using int is to make sure `r = length - 1' is negative if the array is empty. So if you want to use size_t, just add a check in case of empty array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a classic problem in the posted code:

- `m = (l + r) / 2;` may cause an arithmetic overflow for large arrays, invoking undefined behavior. On many architectures, `m` may get a negative value, causing further undefined behavior when dereferencing `array[m]`.  `m` should be computed as

  ```
      m = l + (r - l) / 2;
  ```
- Note that the expression `m = (l + r) / 2;` would still cause problems for unsigned index types if the array is even larger.

To use index type `size_t` and thus handle larger arrays, you must also change the return type to `size_t` and use as a convention a return value of `SIZE_MAX` to mean *not found*.

Here is an alternative using `size_t` index types:

```
size_t binary_search(const unsigned array[], size_t length, unsigned needle) {
    size_t lo = 0, hi = length;
    while (lo < hi) {
        size_t mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if (array[mid] < needle) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    if (lo < length && array[lo] == needle) {
        return lo;
    } else {
        return (size_t)-1;  // SIZE_MAX
    }
}
```